# System.Security.Claims.ClaimType Role doesn't match

Tags: c#, .net, security, jwt

Just trying to understand a problem, that appears in my head to be a bug in the Microsoft System.Security dll, but probably something I am doing incorrectly.

I am trying to custom implement a JWT token. I create the claims and the token:

```
var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(new List<System.Security.Claims.Claim>()
            {
                new System.Security.Claims.Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid, "1"),
                new System.Security.Claims.Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "1"),
            },"Custom");


var securityTokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor()
            {
                AppliesToAddress = Keys.Core.WebsiteDomain,
                TokenIssuerName = Keys.Core.WebsiteDomain,
                Subject = claimsIdentity,
                SigningCredentials = signingCredentials,
            };

            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var plainToken = tokenHandler.CreateToken(securityTokenDescriptor);
            var signedAndEncodedToken = tokenHandler.WriteToken(plainToken);

            return signedAndEncodedToken;
```

I then go to retrieve the token and the User (SID) and Role values:

```
var roleId = stream.Claims.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.Role).Value;
var userId = stream.Claims.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.Sid).Value;
```

Validate Function:

```
private static JwtSecurityToken Validate(string signedAndEncodedToken)
        {
            var tokenHandler = new CustomJwtSecurityTokenHandler();

            var plainTextSecurityKey = Keys.Security.TokenSecret;
            var signingKey = new InMemorySymmetricSecurityKey(
                Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainTextSecurityKey));

            var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                IssuerSigningKey = signingKey
            };

            SecurityToken validatedToken;
            tokenHandler.ValidateToken(signedAndEncodedToken, tokenValidationParameters, out validatedToken);
            var jwtToken = validatedToken as JwtSecurityToken;
            return validatedToken as JwtSecurityToken;
        }
```

Now My UserID (ClaimType.SID) appears to return correctly, but my RoleId (ClaimType.Role) comes back as non existant. If I change x.Type == "role" it works correctly.

On inspection on the Claim.Type SID appears as: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/sid

But Claim.Type Role appears as: Role.

ClaimTypes.Role has the full Schema path.

Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Comment: Can you post a sample token?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realized sometime has passed, but as someone who was surprised by this as well, I did encounter this comment on the `JwtSecurityToken.Claims` property:

**Claim(s) returned will NOT have the `Claim.Type` translated according to `JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap`**

So if you want to use `ClaimTypes` when searching in a decoded token, you can just run it through that dictionary and know that you're not insane or did anything wrong.

```
        Assert.Equal(
            "Nicholas Piasecki", 
            parsedToken
                .Claims
                .Single(x =>
                {
                    var map = JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap;

                    if (map.TryGetValue(x.Type, out var mapped))
                    {
                        return mapped == ClaimTypes.GivenName;
                    }

                    return false;
                })
                .Value);
```